# Intersection of the span of different matrix is empty

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Suppose to have three different matrices $$
\underbrace{A}_{P\times J_a}, \;\; \underbrace{B}_{P\times J_b},\;\;\; \mbox{ and } \underbrace{C}_{P\times J_c}$$
with full column rank, since $P>J_a$, $P>J_b$ and $P>J_c$ we have $rk(A) = J_a$, $rk(B) =J_b$ and $rk(C) =J_c$.

If we assume that the intersection of the span of the three matrices is empty, $span (A) \cap span(B) \cap span(C) = \emptyset$, is that true that the column vectors of the three matrices are linearly independent? Can you prove that?

Comment: Doesn't the column space of every matrix contain the zero vector?

Comment: The column space of every matrix does not contain the zero vector

Comment: Full column rank + $P<J_a$ means $\textrm{rank}(A)=P$, no?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the next counterexample:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$
$B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$
$C=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

In this case the intersection between the column spaces generated by the three matrices is the empty set, that is $span(A)\cap span(B)\cap span(C)=\emptyset$. However, the first columns of $A$ and $B$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: Ok. But the column vector of the concatenated matrix (A,B,C) has to be linearly independent, is that true? In this example the vectors of A and B are linearly independent

Comment: What do you mean by concatenated matrix?